# How to fetch a column from a table(Persistence Database table) into a 'select' list of 'form' in a jsp page

Tags: hibernate, struts2, persistence, hql

I want to fetch a column from a table(Persistence Database table) into a 'select' list of 'form' in a jsp page.
I am using struts2 and hibernate.

My column is 'name' and table is 'Category'
I have made the mapping configuration and bean classes.

code in a 'form' of a jsp page :

```
<s:select label="Select Category :" name="cname" list="categoryList" />
```

My action class :

```
package com.rambo.action;

import beans.Category;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Session;

public class FindCategory extends ActionSupport {

    private List<Category> cl = new ArrayList<Category>();
    private List<String> categoryList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            this.cl = (List<Category>) session.createQuery("from Category").list();
            if (this.cl.isEmpty()) {
                this.addActionError("Sorry.. No category Available. Try again Later.!");
                return ERROR;
            }
            for (int i = cl.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
                categoryList.add(cl.get(i).getName());
            }
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.addActionError("Oops. An Error Encountered...!");
            return ERROR;
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Mapping in Category.hbm.xml :

```
<property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="NAME" length="20" not-null="true" />
        </property>
```

Getter and setter of the bean "Category.java":

```
public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

My glassfish server shows error as :

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: tag 'select', field 'list', name 'cname': The requested list key 'categoryList' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]

root cause tag 'select', field 'list', name 'cname': The requested list key 'categoryList' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]
```

Can some one please point out what may b the error..?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Please solve the another similar problem also.. thanks
[link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463763/getting-error-on-selecting-a-value-from-a-drop-down-select)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a public getter for `categoryList`, otherwise the tag can't access the list.

Also, you're doing too much work in the action, IMO.

Comment: Please solve the another similar problem also.. thanks
[link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463763/getting-error-on-selecting-a-value-from-a-drop-down-select)